# Jquery "this" context

Tags: jquery, css

im trying to do something like

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(this).(".anotherClass").css("z-index","1");
    $(this).(".anotherClass").toggle( "slide",{ direction: "left"  } );    
 });
```

and i already try with

```
$(".className").click(function(){
     $(this).find(".anotherClass").css("z-index","1");
     $(this).find(".anotherClass").toggle( "slide",{ direction: "left"  } );   

});
```

and it keeps saying that " (this) is not defined", i dont know how to get (this) from the context of .anotherClass

Im trying to start the animation if someone click the .className div, but there are a lot of .className divs, so , if you click to one .className just that .anotherClass div shoul be animated, this are my actual divs

```
        <div class="streamPlayer">
            <div class="albumArt">
            </div>

            <div class="onPlay">
                <div class="hiddenOnPlay">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="addPlaylist"></div>
            <div class="downloadSong"></div>
        </div>
```

The jquery

```
  $(".albumArt").click(function() {
      $(".hiddenOnPlay").css("z-index","1");
      $(".hiddenOnPlay").toggle( "slide",{ direction: "left"  } );    
   });
```

Comment: so basically you wanna toggle this if it has the class .anotherClass? or what?

Comment: The second one is the proper syntax and should work just fine.

Comment: In this case, `$(this)` referrers to the clicked element, so, your second piece of code is ok and should work as expected if you have `.anotherClass` **into** `.className`

Comment: Please show your HTML, and explain what you click on and what element's CSS is supposed to change. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: The second version might not do you want, but it shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: My suspicion is that you need `.closest()` instead of `.find()`. `$(this).find()` looks for elements inside `$(this)`, `$(this).closest()` looks for elements that contain `$(this)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments guys the answet that @shaunakde gave me was the one that saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GjQ7/)**

Use `.next().find()`This should work for you,

```
$(".albumArt").click(function() {
      var hiddenPlay = $(this).next().find(".hiddenOnPlay");
      hiddenPlay.css("z-index","1");
      hiddenPlay.toggle();    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i know how to get (this)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $(".albumArt").click(function(event) {
          var hidePlay = $(event.target).next(".onPlay").find(".hiddenOnPlay");
          hidePlay.css("z-index","1");
          hidePlay.toggle( "slide",{ direction: "left"  } );    
    });
```